# networkSecurityConfig not working for http connection

Tags: android, http

I'm testing http connection with apache server on ec2 and my android app.
Connection works fine on emulator(API 24) but it won't work on my Samsung Galaxy S10(API 29).
Tried everything related to configuring `network_security_config.xml` but nothing worked.
In my `build.gradle` minSdkVersion is 16 and targetSdkversino is 29. Below are my trials. (Let's assume i'm trying to connect to IP address of 1.2.3.4)

#### 1) Adding custom network_security_config.xml

in `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">
            1.2.3.4
        </domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

in my manifest,

```
    <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

#### 2) Setting usesClearTextTraffic as true

in my manifest,

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

#### 3) Applying both 1) and 2)

in my manifest,

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

#### 4) Setting tools:targetApi with 3)

in my manifest,

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    tools:targetApi="29"
```

#### 5) using base-config instead of domain-config

in `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

I have no idea what's wrong here.

Comment: It's possible the `<domain>` tag does not support IP addresses, only domain names :/

Comment: Solved! Problem was that I didn't allow ip address of my phone to my ec2 server in aws security group settings smh.. Works like a charm now.